# SSH failing to connect, No supported key exchange algorithms

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ssh, ssh-keys

There are numerous questions with the same title however none of the solutions apply to my issue. I get the following lines of error in my `sshd` log:

```
Jan  6 21:57:55 <computer name> sshd[30103]: Received signal 15; terminating.
Jan  6 21:57:55 <computer name> sshd[30175]: Server listening on 127.0.0.1 port 22.
Jan  6 21:58:00 <computer name> sshd[30184]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
Jan  6 21:58:00 <computer name> sshd[30184]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
Jan  6 21:58:00 <computer name> sshd[30184]: Disabling protocol version 1. Could not load host key
Jan  6 21:58:00 <computer name> sshd[30184]: fatal: No supported key exchange algorithms [preauth]
```

But the key files `/etc/ssh/...` exist and have the right permission: running `la /etc/ssh/`

```
total 276K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 222K Jan  6 22:01 moduli
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.2K Jan  6 20:45 ssh_config
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.8K Jan  6 21:57 sshd_config
-rw------- 1 root root  464 Jan  6 21:23 ssh_host_ed25519_key
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  109 Jan  6 21:23 ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
-rw------- 1 root root 3.3K Jan  6 21:24 ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  753 Jan  6 21:24 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  338 Jan  6 17:44 ssh_import_id
```

I've recently **change** my configurations to make it more secure. I've tried regenerating all key files but no luck. The client is the same machine (Trying to connect to `ssh localhost`) but no luck.

Comment: And what changes did you make?

Comment: Whatever changes you made, undo them and redo them one at a time until you find the specific change that breaks your connections. Then ask a specific question with details of the change.

Comment: I just restricted the algorithms and keys formats used. Host and client (which are the same machine) share a similar config file therefore they must be compatible

Comment: What's the reason for downvote? That's why nobody posts new questions that often anymore!

Comment: Lemme guess - you followed the instructions in [this article](https://stribika.github.io/2015/01/04/secure-secure-shell.html) without understanding what they actually do...

Comment: I understand the client related part but not the server side!

Comment: Aside from guessing do you know how to fix this issue and use HostKeys with passphrase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I found the issue. I removed the server and re-installed it. If I let the generted key files `rsa` and `ed25519` stay it works. If I remove and regenerate them with the following command it **BREAKS**

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f ssh_host_ed25519_key < /dev/null
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f ssh_host_rsa_key < /dev/null
```

**EDIT** Finally found the real issue. If I put passphrase on my keyfiles then it won't work and I'll get the error that connection is closed.